# How to append a list of strings

Tags: python

I would like to append a list of string in python as below:

```
messages = ["hello","hi"]
```

Expected output

```
messages = ["hello","hi","bye"]
```

Her is an example where i do have an error :

> "str object has no attribute "append" "

```
messages = ["really","hey"]
user = ["0.0.0.0"]
serv.bind(('0.0.0.0',12800))
msg, addr = serv.recvfrom(1024)
msg = msg.decode()
user.append(addr)
messages.append(msg)
```

Full code :

```
chat = ['Bienvenu dans le chat de Dungeons !','Welcome on Dungeon\'s chat']
user = ["really","hey"]
pseudo = ["foo","this"]
isConnect = [0]



serv = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
user_tab = 0

serv.bind(('0.0.0.0',12800))



while(1):

    msg, addr = serv.recvfrom(1024)
    msg = msg.decode()

    if (msg.find("[pseudo]")!=-1):
        firstPlace = msg.find("[pseudo]")
        secondPlace = msg.find("[pswd]")
        if firstPlace != -1 and secondPlace != -1:
            pseu = msg[firstPlace+9:secondPlace]
            pswd = msg[secondPlace+7:]
            print("New client with infos ip ",addr, ",pseudo", pseu, "and password", pswd)
            user.append(addr)
            pseudo.append(pseu)
            isConnect.append("1")
            send_connect="connect"
            serv.sendto(send_connect.encode(),addr)
```

Comment: Do not name your variable `list` or any other Python types or keywords.

Comment: Look over the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial).

Comment: @Xavier59 you **will not** get the error you indicate in your question with the code in your question. Period. Are you sure you are running that **exact** code?

Comment: Actually it is working 1-2 times but then, doing this error. I can't understand why

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> l = ["hello","hi"]
>>> l.append("bye")
>>> l
['hello', 'hi', 'bye']
```

Comment: Hi, when i do stuff like that, i have an error :
"str object has not attribute append"

Comment: No you don't, I just showed you that it works. If you are writing code that is producing errors, post a question that shows your **actual code** and the **full error message** that you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, but i don't really understand it.
Here is what I changed :

```
pseu = str(msg[firstPlace+9:secondPlace])
```